# cannot locate a web element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I just want to write a simple log in script for Apple website:
[Sign In](https://secure2.store.apple.com/shop/sign_in?c=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5hcHBsZS5jb20vc2hvcC9iYWd8MWFvczVjNGU3ZWNjZjgwODVjNWY4NDk0OTA0ODJhMDc2Y2FkNmU3ODJkOTE&o=O01LV0gy&r=SXYD4UDAPXU7P7KXF&s=aHR0cHM6Ly9zZWN1cmUyLnN0b3JlLmFwcGxlLmNvbS9zaG9wL2NoZWNrb3V0L3N0YXJ0P3BsdG49RkNBRjZGQjR8MWFvczAyZmZkZjQwNTgwOGI4ZTNkMDQ5MWRiM2NmZmExYTgxNzRkZTllMjY&t=SXYD4UDAPXU7P7KXF&up=t)

The ID and password form cannot be located properly. 
Actually, I tried a lot of thing like:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='email']")
```

or

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='login-appleId']")
```

and

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='login-appleId']")
```

I did not find any iframe in this page. And I tried same thing for customer checkout button, also same problem happens.

Any suggestions would be appreciate!

Best,
Luke

Comment: The thing is that you should give enough time to the web page to be loaded.There is a theory on Implisit wait & Explecit wait.Try it out, wich schedule some time period to wait for the elements to be loaded to the browser window.Or you could use Thread.sleep(), by the way which is not highly recommended approach.

Comment: Try `time.sleep(few_seconds)` after you open page, that should help

Answer (score 1):

You can Follow this code .. It works ..!!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('E:\chromedriver.exe') #location
driver.get('url') #https://secure2.store.apple.com/shop/sign_in?c=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5hcHBsZS5jb20vc2hvcC9iYWd8MWFvczVjNGU3ZWNjZjgwODVjNWY4NDk0OTA0ODJhMDc2Y2FkNmU3ODJkOTE&o=O01LV0gy&r=SXYD4UDAPXU7P7KXF&s=aHR0cHM6Ly9zZWN1cmUyLnN0b3JlLmFwcGxlLmNvbS9zaG9wL2NoZWNrb3V0L3N0YXJ0P3BsdG49RkNBRjZGQjR8MWFvczAyZmZkZjQwNTgwOGI4ZTNkMDQ5MWRiM2NmZmExYTgxNzRkZTllMjY&t=SXYD4UDAPXU7P7KXF&up=t

def find_by_xpath(locator):
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, locator))
    )
   return element
class FormPage(object):
    def fill_form(self, data):
        find_by_xpath('//input[@name = "login-appleId"]').send_keys(data['usr')
        find_by_xpath('//input[@name = "login-password"]').send_keys(data['pwd'])
        return self 

    def submit(self):
        find_by_xpath('//input[@id = "sign-in"]').click()

 data = {
       'usr': 'xx@apple.com',
       'pwd': 'xxxx'
       }

if __name__=="__main__":
     FormPage().fill_form(data).submit()
     driver.quit() # closes the webbrowser
```

Hope it is helpful to you
Thanks.!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("login-appleId")
driver.find_element_by_id("login-password")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in `WebDriver` there are scenarios where the `WebElement` isn't loaded properly on `DOM` and webdriver tries to find it. So to handle these kind of scenarios there are 2 types of wait provided by `WebDriver` library.

You just need to implement one of these based on your requirements.

1. [Implicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits)
2. [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

I suggest you to implement one of these and then try to execute your script.

Comment: It doesn't work always as you expect, usually `time.sleep(some_seconds)` is enough

Comment: `time.sleep(some_seconds)` also has some disadvantage. It blocks your UI thread for exact time that you have mentioned in the parameter. lets say you have given the wait time as 60seconds and the element is loaded in 1 second then also the Thread is stop for entire 60 seconds that isn't the case with `Implicit Waits or Explicit Waits`